# Junction Box size/type requirement

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box

Can a standard blue junction box be used for indoor wiring purpose?

Lets say I have one single gang box of 24 cu. in. which is placed as junction box to connect three 14/2 cables inside it. I know its within the box size. But does a junction box for this reason has to be specific one, I meant more deeper/wider ?

Edited: Added a picture to help other newbie.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, a "gang box" is something else (jobsite toolbox, usually). Here we're talking about junction boxes or device boxes. The phrase "double gang", for example, just describes nominal size of a junction box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use a “device” box as a junction box.

The same rules apply you have to securely mount it.
wires stapled within 8” (my inspectors do not consider the alligator clamps good for 12”)

and it will need a solid cover.

I have done this throughout my career as long as the box is stamped or you use the chart from the code book for fill it is code compliant to use as a simple splice / junction box.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it can be used strictly as a junction box as long as it's covered and remains accessible. In cases like this, I have usually seen, and done, a two gang box with a single gang mud ring. It gives a bit more flexibility and you could add an outlet in the future.